# Como copiar o sumário de um método com overload em C#?

Tags: c#, comentários, sobrecarga

Estou criando uma aplicação onde nas classes eu tenho uma série de *overload*'s para otimizar o desempenho e a flexibilidade da mesma. Ex:

```
public class Calc 
{
    // método original com sumário

    /// <summary>
    /// soma "a" com "b"
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int soma(int a, int b) => a + b;

    // métodos complementares de conversão (overload) sem comentários

    public int soma(string a, int b) => soma(int.Parse(a), b);
    public int soma(string a, string b) => soma(int.Parse(a), int.Parse(b));
}
```

Existe alguma forma de, quando eu chamar um dos métodos complementares, ele me mostrar a doc do método original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem que ser na mão. Se fosse com `override` teria como resolver.

O caso mais comum de *overload* dá para evitar o seu uso com argumentos *default*, inclusive é melhor, mas neste caso onde muda o tipo não dá, porque de qualquer forma em boa parte dos casos muda a semântica e a descrição deveria ser diferente.

Em geral copiar e colar no código em algo no mesmo tipo não costuma ser difícil e como o contrato deve ser bem estável não deve ter que mudar muito. De qualquer forma se fizer uma alteração sem prestar muita atenção nas sobrecargas pode cometer um erro, por isso não acho que seja uma falha grave da ferramenta. É aquela coisa, comentários são complicados, de uma certa forma eles chegam até violar o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

Comment: entendi... então realmente não tem como... fazer o que né... obrigado mesmo assim